Check function parameter type during runtime
i have an vue 3 library with typescript. Currently the library is released with a FooFunction type, but i need to change the function definition and change the parameter to another type(FooExtendedFunction). My goal is to do no breaking change. Currently i am trying to check the parameter type of the function to know which parameter i need to pass, but i can't get this to work.
interface FooObj {
  id: string
}
type FooExtendedFunction = (fooObj: FooObj) => void
type FooFunction = (id: string) => void | FooExtendedFunction

// Properties from a vue component
interface Props {
  fooFunc: FooFunction
}

function isIdFunction(fn: any): fn is (id: string) => void {
  return typeof fn === 'function' && fn.length === 1
}

function isFooObjFunction(fn: any): fn is (fooObj: FooObj) => void {
  return typeof fn === 'function' && fn.length === 1 && !isIdFunction(fn)
}

How can i check during runtime for the correct parameter type id as string or fooObj as FooObj. If this is not possible maybe there is another way to solve such an issue.
What is the correct way to solve this without a breaking change?

You are asking how to check the accepted arguments of a function are of  a correct type? It's impossible, function will accept any arguments at runtime.
Why are you trying to validate it anyway? checking if it's a function and calling it normally should be enough, it's not a job of a child component to verify function passed from parent.

But i need to check if the user of the component passed a function with a string as parameter or a FooObj as parameter. If i don't check this this would lead to an breaking change.

Making sure the passed prop is correct is on the parent. There is no such thing as argument type at runtime. Function can be called with any arguments, it may break the code inside the function sure, but there is nothing stopping you from calling it with any arguments.
